# KVO addObserver crashes on iOS 13

Tags: ios, crash, key-value-observing

Strange exception started to occur when running stable project on iOS 13.

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

XCode provides no additional info and no stacktrace.
Here is the code causing the exception

```
    self.collectionView?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: [NSKeyValueObservingOptions.old], context: nil)
    self.viewTranformObserver = self.collectionView?.observe(\.contentSize, options: [.old]) { (_, _) in
        self.collectionViewContentSizeChanged()
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: why do you need     self.collectionView?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: [NSKeyValueObservingOptions.old], context: nil)?

Comment: good question, I'm just dealing with code written not by me) I think, it can be refactored. however it would be nice to know, why it happened. collectionViewContentSizeChanged() function changes collectionView height based on contentSize.height value